# Capistrano overrides routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem: Always I ran **cap production deploy** Capistrano overrides my **config/routes.rb** to default rails code.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

**CapFile**

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/nginx'
require 'capistrano/puma'
require 'capistrano/puma/nginx'

Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

**config/deploy.rb**

```
lock '3.6.1'

set :application, 'demo-ror'
set :repo_url, '<my_git_repo>'
set :scm, :git
set :branch, :master
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/demo-ror'
set :tmp_dir, '/home/ubuntu/tmp'
set :pty, true
set :format, :airbrussh
set :format_options, command_output: true, log_file: 'log/capistrano.log', color: :auto, truncate: :auto
set :keep_releases, 5
set :keep_assets, 2
set :app_server, true
set :app_server_host, "127.0.0.1"
set :app_server_port, 8080

# nginx
...

# puma
...
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'
end
```